# For different IIS Applications that are under the same IIS Web Site, how to configure separate Forms Authentication?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis-7, forms-authentication

I have an Asp.Net MVC application using Forms Authentication that is published to the same IIS Web Site under different Application Names:

```
Default Web Site/Dashboard
Default Web Site/Partner
```

Using Chrome, if I go to the `Dashboard` instance and log in, everything seems to work fine.  If I open a separate browser window and navigate to the `Partner` instance, I am prompted to log in as expected.  Upon logging into `Partner` instance, everything seems to work fine as well.  **The problem arises when I go back to my previous browser window and try to access an authenticated resource on the `Dashboard` instance, where I get redirected to the Login page as if I had somehow been logged out.**  If I log in again on the `Dashboard` instance, thing work fine again.  But if I go to the `Partner` instance, I discover that I get logged out there.  It seems that the act of logging into the other application instance somehow logs me out of the previous one.  I did some goggling and it appears the problem is caused by my forms authentication cookie settings.  Here is what I was using:

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="~/Account/LogOn"
         timeout="1576800"/>
</authentication>
```

I did not specify a cookie path explicitly, so I figured the cookie path might be shared by the application instances so it was getting overwritten.  So I tried to specify a cookie path explicitly.  So when I publish `Dashboard`, I used this:

```
 <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms loginUrl="~/Account/LogOn"
             timeout="1576800"
             cookieless="UseCookies"
             path="/Dashboard" />
 </authentication>
```

And for `Partner`, I used this:

```
 <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms loginUrl="~/Account/LogOn"
             timeout="1576800"
             cookieless="UseCookies"
             path="/Partner" />
 </authentication>
```

However this did not work at all.  With these settings I can not even log in and out properly.  **My goal is to have the Dashboard and Partner instances be totally independent for forms authentication, so logging into one does not influence the other.  Is this possible without putting them in different IIS Web Site names?**

Comment: Did you try setting unique the cookie names for each application.. e.g. <forms name="DashBoard" /> ?

Comment: @cecilphillip That seems to do the trick.  Please post it as an answer and I will accept it.  Thx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the web.config for each application, set unique name for the cookie name in your authentication tags

```
 <authentication name="DashBoard" mode="Forms">
 <forms loginUrl="~/Account/LogOn" />
</authentication>
```

Comment: Had the same question and just found your answer.  Confirming, but with a slight correction: `name="CookieName"` is an attribute of `<forms>` element, not `<authentication>`.  Thanks!